# If I buy one game DLC on one account will it go to my other account?

Tags: xbox-network, jurassic-world-evolution

I want to buy a DLC for a game, but I can't remember my old account password (I can still get into it but I can't buy stuff in the Microsoft store), so if I buy the DLC on a different account will it be able to go on the other account? If not, then I really don't want to spend $20 each on a DLC for a separate account.
I have already tried to reset my password but it will not work.

Comment: Unlike vowels on wheel of fortune, punctuation is free. Please consider making use of it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The DLC will *only* be available to the account that you purchase it on, unfortunately.